# Декодирование Байтовой строки в формате ID3v2 с присутствием разных кодировок в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, id3v2

Есть Байтовая строка

```
`b"ID3\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1fvTIT2\x00\x00\x00'\x00\x00\x01\xff\xfe\x15\x04:\x040\x04B\x045\x04@\x048\x04=\x041\x04N\x04@\x043\x045\x04@\x04 \x00'\x001\x003\x00TPE1\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x01\xff\xfe\x1a\x04C\x04@\x040\x04@\x040\x04TRCK\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x01\xff\xfe1\x006\x00/\x001\x006\x00TCON\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x01\xff\xfeI\x00n\x00d\x00i\x00e\x00 \x00R\x00o\x00c\x00k\x00TPE2\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x01\xff\xfe\x1a\x04C\x04@\x040\x04@\x040\x04TYER\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x01\xff\xfe2\x000\x001\x004\x00TALB\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x01\xff\xfe\x10\x04@\x04E\x048\x04<\x045\x044\x04\
```

В ней присутствую символы Кодировки Utf-16 И ISO-8859-1, причем сказано, что если символы кодируются в utf-16 то будет вначале стоять \xff\xfe\, каким образом можно декодировать строку так, что бы получился правильный результат?

Comment: `if b"\xff\xfe" == bytestring[3:5]` ... но лучше сначала разбить на блоки.

Comment: Что вы делали чтобы решить проблему? Покажите код.

Comment: я не знаю как это сделать, пробовал через регуляргу заменить, по байтово сравнить, все не то.

Comment: А в каких позициях должны быть FFFE ? Я вот пока вижу что после ID3  вообще идут двоичные данные. вы бы показали как добираетесь до того кусока строки в котором собственно текст, а не другая информация.

Comment: Посмотрел стандарт ... все еще хуже. там может быть любой BOM. FFFE и FEFF говорящие о разном порядке байт в строке. Причем бывают же разные версии ID3... Может стоит взять готовую библиотеку для работы с ним на том же официальном сайте стандарта http://id3.org/Implementations

Comment: это не текст, а бинарный формат http://id3.org/d3v2.3.0 Попробуйте существующие библиотеки как  @Mike предложил